# How to apply Lax-Milgram theorem on one dimensional Poisson equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to show that the following equation has a unique solution in $[0,1]$.
$$
-u''+u=f~~in~~ \Omega=(0,1)
$$
and boundary conditions are $u(0)=u(1)$ and $u'(0)=u'(1)$.

Firstly, I found the weak formulation of the above equation and I got,
$$
a(u,v) = \int_{}^{1}(u'v'+uv)dx
$$ and
$$
L(v) = \int_{0}^{1}vdx
$$
where $v \in V=\{v \in H^{1}([0,1])|~v(0)=v(1)~\}$.
To apply the Lax-Milgram theorem, I am little confused in showing the coercive by using the Poincare inequality.
$$
a(v,v)=\int_{0}^{1}(|v'|^2+v^2)dx \ge \int_{0}^{1}|v'|^2dx\ge\alpha \|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2
$$
To apply the Poincare inequality, I need to take $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Can anyone let me know how to justify this step?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Poincare here, $a(u,u)$ is already the square of the norm in $H^1(0,1)$. There is no reason to drop the $v^2$ and then try to find a lower bound that includes it, just leave it there.